# Drawing a Power Flow arrow in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Is it possible to draw a power flow arrow in `circuitikz`?

I'd like to draw an arrow point away from the voltage source on the right that indicates the flow of power towards the left.

What I'm after is not a current arrow, but a larger arrow that sits above the circuit instead of on the wire.

Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0)   to [sV, l=$V_{\text{upstream}}$] (0,2)
        to [R, l=$R$] (2,2)
        to [L, l=$X_l$] (4,2)
        to [sV, l=$V_{\text{DG}}$] (4,0)
        -- (0,0);
;\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `\draw` command from `TikZ` to place the arrow at the desired location:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0)   to [sV, l=$V_{\text{upstream}}$] (0,2)
        to [R, l=$R$] (2,2)
        to [L, l=$X_l$] (4,2)
        to [sV , l=$V_{\text{DG}}$] (4,0)
        -- (0,0);
\draw[-latex] (2.5,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite, sorry, I should've been more specific. I'm after a larger arrow that sits above the circuit. Thanks though! Just edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Fabian: I've updated my answer. Is something like that waht you need?